# Regarding testing & compliance requirements of the products for UKCA declaration

Tags: certification

I do have a doubt regarding compliance of the Product for the UKCA marking.
If the product has been tested according to the EMC/EMI & Safety requirements for the EU declaration is it sufficient for UKCA declaration also?

According to my research the harmonized standards are the same for the both CE & UKCA. The only difference what I have found is the mention of UKCA statutory instruments available for UKCA marking. But is it provide any further testing requirements except CE?

If there is any further requirements than what I have mentioned please do let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is mostly Brexit politics more so than engineering. This might be helpful: https://www.gov.uk/guidance/using-the-ukca-marking

Comment: Yeah Lundin I do have referred this website before but still I do have the same doubts which I have asked here. Kindly share the details if possible.